# Does Picasso library can load images from unparsed String?

Tags: android, parsing, picasso

I'm writing an Android application which receives RSS feeds. In RecyclerView I'm showing title of feed and its image. The URL of image lays in description tag like that

```
<description>
<![CDATA[

**<img src="https://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/s-
chifyhXd--/c_fit,fl_progressive,q_80,w_636/mufkwgdjt3tolcis7xl0.jpg"/>**

<p>iOS: Other unimportant tags, information>Read more...</a></p>
</description>
```

Picasso code snippet

```
public static void loadImage(String imageUrl, ImageView imageView){
    Picasso.get()
            .load(imageUrl)
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .error(R.drawable.tech_crunch_logo)
            .into(imageView);
}
```

I've suddenly found that I don't need to parse  content to get image URL: I can simply get full description's CDATA and Picasso will download the image I want. So, anybody could explain me the behavior of .load operator? Why I'm getting image and not mistake? Does it's cleaned with

Comment: _anybody could explain me the behavior of .load operator?.._ Of course, picasso docs will do this....

Comment: you can even browse picasso sources to get what you want.\